# ¿Como hacer el metodo de burbuja para ordenar Strings?

Tags: java, array, poo, bucle-for

estoy con una clase Sistema donde debo crear un metodo para ordenar alfabéticamente los nombres de usuarios y la única forma de hacerlo es con el método de burbuja ya que solo me enseñaron eso para ordenar arrays.
Lo hice asi :

```
public void ordenarPorUsuario() {

int i = 0;
int j = 0;
Usuario aux ;

for (i = 0; i < lista.length; i++) {

    for ( j = 0; j < lista.length -1; j++) {

        if(lista[j].getUsuario().compareTo(lista[j+1].getUsuario())>0) {

            aux = lista[j];
            lista[j] = lista[j+1]; //en esta parte debo poner
            lista[j+1]=aux; //lista sin el getUsuario() por que 
          // sino me dice que lista[j].getUsuario() no es una variable
          // y me sugiere que la variable aux la cambie a tipo Usuario, por 
          //que antes le puse de tipo String.

        }

      }

   }


}
```

Cuando lo ejecuto me sale el nombre de mi package punto Usuario @ y unos numeros que no se que me quiere decir.
Y no se si en el main lo llame de forma correcta , no se cual puede ser el problema.

Les voy a dejar el codigo para que vean lo que hice
(el metodo de ordenamiento esta en la clase sistema):

```
public class Usuario {

private String contrasena;
private String usuario;

public Usuario(String usuario , String contrasena){

    this.contrasena = contrasena;
    this.usuario= usuario;
}

public void setContrasena(String contrasena){

    this.contrasena = contrasena;
}

public String getContrasena(){

    return this.contrasena;
}

public void setUsuario(String usuario){

    this.usuario = usuario;
}

public String getUsuario(){

    return this.usuario;
 }


}

public class Sistema {

private String nombre;
private Usuario lista[];
int usuariosIngresados=0;

public Sistema(String nombre , int cantidadDeUsuario){

    this.nombre = nombre ;
    this.lista = new Usuario[cantidadDeUsuario];

}

public void setNombre(String nombre){

    this.nombre = nombre ;
}


public String getNombre(){

    return this.nombre;
}

public Usuario [] getLista (){

    return this.lista;
}

public void agregarUsuarios(Usuario usuario){


    lista[usuariosIngresados]= usuario;
    usuariosIngresados++;
}

public boolean loguearse(String nombreDeUsuario , String contrasena){



   boolean estado = false;

    for(int i = 0 ; i< lista.length ; i++ ){


    if(nombreDeUsuario.equals(lista[i].getUsuario())&& contrasena.equals(lista[i].getContrasena())){

       estado= true ;
       break;
    }

    else{

        estado = false;

    }

    }


    return estado;

  }

public void ordenarPorUsuario() {

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    Usuario aux ;

    for (i = 0; i < lista.length; i++) {

        for ( j = 0; j < lista.length -1; j++) {

            if(lista[j].getUsuario().compareTo(lista[j+1].getUsuario())>0) {

                aux = lista[j];
                lista[j] = lista[j+1];
                lista[j+1]=aux;


            }

        }

    }


  }


}

import java.util.Scanner;

public class PruebaSistema{
     public static void main (String [] args){

 /****************************************************************/

 //Variables de la clase Sistema 

 String nombre = " ";
  int cantidadDeUsuarios = 0;

 //Variable extra 

 int i = 0;
 int opciones = 0;

 //Variables de la clase Usuario

   String usuario =" ";
    String contrasena = " ";



    /**********************************************************************/

  Scanner teclado = new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre del sistema : ");
    nombre = teclado.nextLine();
   System.out.println("Ingrese la cantidad de usuarios : ");
  cantidadDeUsuarios = teclado.nextInt();
   Sistema sistema1 = new Sistema (nombre , cantidadDeUsuarios);


 //MENU DE OPCIONES

 while(opciones<=2){

   System.out.println("Ingrese una opcion : ");
   System.out.println("1.Agregar usuarios. ");
   System.out.println("2.Loguearse en el sistema.");
   System.out.println("3.Mostrar los usuarios ordenados.");
   opciones = teclado.nextInt();

switch(opciones){

    case 1 :

    for(i = 0 ; i < cantidadDeUsuarios ; i++){

      System.out.println((i+1)+".Ingrese un nombre de usuario : ");
      usuario=teclado.next();
      System.out.println((i+1)+".Ingrese una contrasena : ");
      contrasena = teclado.next();
      sistema1.agregarUsuarios(new Usuario (usuario , contrasena));
    }

    break;

    case 2 :

     for(i = 0 ; i < cantidadDeUsuarios ; i++){

      System.out.println((i+1)+".Usuario : ");
      usuario= teclado.next();
      System.out.println((i+1)+".Contrasena : ");
      contrasena = teclado.next();
     System.out.println(sistema1.loguearse(usuario , contrasena));


    }



    break;

    case 3 : 

        for ( i = 0; i < sistema1.getLista().length; i++) {

            sistema1.ordenarPorUsuario();
            System.out.println(sistema1.getLista()[i]);
        }



    default :

    System.out.println("El menu solo tiene 3 opciones.Intente de nuevo.");

    break;   
    }
 }




    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que dices, sospecho que lo que está mostrando es la clase y el HashCode del array, en lugar de su valor real. La salida del programa será algo parecido a `paquete.nombreClase@1a2b3c`.

Prueba a utilizar `Arrays.toString(tuArray)` en el println que causa el error.

Puedes sobreescribir el método `toString()` en tu clase.

```
@Override
public String toString() 
{ 
    return X;// modifica X con la salida que desees
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A lo que te refieres con que no sabes que es, entiendo que es lo siguiente: javaapplication56.usuario@28d93b30 (algo similar), es la memoria de pila, básicamente la dirección de memoria dónde está guardado tu objeto. 
Con:  System.out.println(sistema1.getLista()[i]); no estás indicando que quieres que te muestre, basicamente te muestra la memoria del objeto. Yo cambiaría esa línea por lo siguiente:

```
String nombreUsuario = sistema1.getLista()[i].getUsuario(); //ahora pillamos el nombre del usuario por cada vuelta según la posición del objeto [i]
System.out.println(nombreUsuario); //mostramos el nombre
```

Por otra parte vi que en el while lo tienes (opciones <= 2) // ese dos creo que lo cambiaría por un 3.

Espero haberte ayudado, un saludo.